# VBA Macro With Password Still Operates When Entered Incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in an Excel sheet that refreshes a SQL query but is password protected--or so I thought. How the macro should work is when you click the button, a password prompt appears and if entered correctly, the query refreshes. If entered incorrectly, nothing should happen.

What I recently discovered is that even if someone enters the password incorrectly, the query refreshes anyways. What would I enter into my code to stop the macro from running if the password is incorrect?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim password As Variant
 password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password Protected")

Select Case password
     Case Is = False
         'do nothing
     Case Is = "Select15"
         Range("A1").Value = "Code"
     Case Else
         MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
End Select


 For Each sh In Worksheets
 If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
 Next

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


End Sub
```

Comment: your refresh it o/s the password check.  it needs to be in the cast "Select15" bit

Comment: Just a general comment - password protection in an Excel workbook is relatively easily broken/gotten around. Do a search online for just "break Excel password" or "get around Excel password" and you'll get tons of hits.  (This is something you're noticing too, just thought to add an additional word of caution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim password As Variant
 password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password Protected")

Select Case password
     Case Is = False
         'do nothing
          exit sub
     Case Is = "Select15"
         Range("A1").Value = "Code"
     Case Else
         MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
         exit sub
End Select


 For Each sh In Worksheets
 If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
 Next

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll


End Sub
```

You should exit the sub, if the password is not the correct one. 
--^^

Or you can create a boolean `bCorrect`, to keep the result of the password and exit, if it is false.--v

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim password As Variant
    Dim bCorrect As Boolean

    password = Application.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password Protected")

    Select Case password

    Case Is = False
        'do nothing
    Case Is = "Select15"
        bCorrect = True
        Range("A1").value = "Code"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
    End Select

    If Not bCorrect Then Exit Sub

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the "exit sub" line and now it's working like originally planned.

Answer (score 0):

Any value your user enters (except -1) is coded as "False", so your first case is being triggered.  Check if the password is correct as your first option.

Comment: The `False` leg of the `Select Case` statement will only be triggered if the user cancels the input box (in which case `password` will be a `Variant/Boolean` containing `False`) or if they enter something like `0` as the password (in which case `password` will be a `Variant/String` containing `"0"` but which will then be coerced to a `Boolean` so that it can be compared to the `False`).  Any other integer value entered will be coerced to `True`, and any non-integer or text value won't be able to be coerced to a `Boolean` at all.